# cin not accepting user input in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in programming, and I'm trying to make a program that calculated how much radiation you've been exposed to throughout your life. For some reason, the 'cin' in my xray function doesn't accept user input, and just exits with code 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
bool nearpowerplant;
int XRay; // the amount of times you got an x-ray
double tRads = 0; // your total dose of radiation in your lifetime, measured in mSv (millisievert)
int age;

//the sleep function
void sleep() {
    Sleep(1000); // 1000 miliseconds = 1 second
}
/*
 >system("CLS")< for clear the console
 */

//introduction and pretty much the menu
void intro() {

    cout << "Welcome to the Radiation Level Calculator" << endl;
    sleep();
    cout << "Conceptualized and created by Anatoly Zavyalov" << endl;
    sleep();
    cout << "Press the ENTER key to begin." << endl;
    cin.get();

}
//introduction to general questions
void genintro() {

    // intro to the medical
    system("CLS");
    sleep();
    cout << "Let's begin with general questions." << endl;
    sleep();
    cout << "Press the ENTER key to continue." << endl;
    cin.get();

}

//medical questions
void Age() {

    //age
    system("CLS");
    cout << "How old are you?\n" << endl;
    sleep();
    cin >> age;

    if (age <= 0) {
        cout << "Your age can't be less or equal to 0." << endl;
        Age();
    }

    else {
        tRads += (age * 2);
        sleep();
        cout << tRads << endl;
    }

}

//live close to powerplant?
void powerplant() {
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Do you live within 75 kilometers of a nuclear powerplant?" << endl;
    sleep();
    cout << "If yes, type YES. If no, type NO." << endl;
    cin >> nearpowerplant;

    if (nearpowerplant = "YES") {
        tRads += (age * 0.01);
    }
    else {}

    sleep();
    cout << tRads << endl;
}


void xray() {
    system("CLS");
    cout << "How many times have you had an x-ray?\n" << endl;
    sleep();
    cin >> XRay;
    if (XRay < 0) {
        cout << "You can't have an x-ray a negative amount of times." << endl;
    }
    else {
        tRads += (XRay * 3.1);
    }
    sleep();
    cout << tRads << endl;
}





//main function, put all of the loops into here
int main() {

    intro(); // the introduction

    genintro(); // medical intro

    Age(); // asks for age

    powerplant(); // asks if lives close to powerplant

    xray(); // asks for x-ray

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I have edited the post to include the whole code. By the way, I am using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: What is that sleep() function doing, and why are you using it?

Comment: You've got a lot to learn about C++ if you think a function should be jamming things into global variables. You may want to get a [primer on how C++ is intended to be used](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do). One of the hazards of C++ is there's many, many ways you *can* do things, but a far smaller number of ways you *should*.

Comment: How does cin exit with 0? Describe exactly what happens.

Comment: OK, that's the definition of sleep(), but why are you calling it before you perform  input?

Comment: Is something (the prompt) shown? Maybe the problem is in other code!?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, I haven't included the majority of the code as I didn't think it was important. Should I make another post with the whole code to clear things up?

Comment: Remove the sleep function, remove the recursive call to xray, and see if that fixes things.

Comment: How would I make it ask the question again if the integer is below 0 (which I don't want)

Comment: @NeilButterworth no, it didn't fix the issue. please answer my question above.

Comment: Use a loop, but forget about that error checking for the time being.

Comment: You could change the type of ``XRay`` to ``unsigned int``. However did you test this small bunch of code without the other code? You should return after recursive call when wrong

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't accept user input"? The program will always exit with a return value of zero, as you have hard-coded that into it.

Comment: @cmdLP i tested the snippet of code and it seemed to work perfectly. I will edit the post to include the whole code.

Comment: Off topic: `if (nearpowerplant = "YES") {` Looks like an accidental assignment.

Comment: @user4581301 I want it to do nothing when nearpowerplant is false. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Mind you, `nearpowerplant` isn't a string. You read a `string` into a `bool` and `cin`'s [going to be in the fail state](http://ideone.com/WEoqcS), causing your visible bug.

Comment: I declared nearpowerplant as a bool, and it seemed to do the trick anyways.

Comment: It doesn't do the trick. `if (nearpowerplant = "YES") {` takes the address of the string literal "YES" and, since it's not null, sets `nearpowerplant` to true. Since the result is true, the if will always enter. You almost want `if (nearpowerplant == "YES") {`, but that also won't work and at this point I might as well write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool nearpowerplant;
```

`nearpowerplant` is a bool. It is true or false. That is it. It's worth noting that there is no reason for this variable to be globally accessible and consuming storage for the entire run of the program. It is used twice in the program, both times in the same function. It should be an Automatic variable scoped by the function that uses it.

```
cout << "If yes, type YES. If no, type NO." << endl;
cin >> nearpowerplant;
```

Reading "YES" or "NO" into a variable of type `bool` fails. `cin` cannot convert the string input into a boolean value and `cin` stops accepting input until the error is cleared. It's also a good idea to remove the garbage input that caused `cin` to fail or guess what? `cin`'s just going to fail again. There are hundreds of SO questions on how to handle this, so I'm just going to drop keywords here: `clear` and `ignore`.

Takeaways: Make sure the data entry matches the type of the data being entered into and test the stream after every read to make sure the read succeeded.

eg:

```
if (cin >> nearpowerplant)
{
    // do stuff
}
else
{
    // clean up
}
```

This solves OP's visible error, but since it is heavily entwined with the next bug they are likely to find, we might as well cover it as well.

```
if (nearpowerplant = "YES") {
    tRads += (age * 0.01);
}
else {}
```

`if (nearpowerplant = "YES") {` uses `=` (assignment) where it should use `==` (comparison). C++ is unforgiving here because this will compile. What it really did was takes the address of the string literal "YES", test that it's not null, and set `nearpowerplant` to the result. Since the address of the string literal is never going to be NULL, the result is always true, and when the if tests the result, the `if` will always enter.

Eg: http://ideone.com/4QL2jn

So what we need is something more like

```
cout << "If yes, type YES. If no, type NO." << endl;
string temp;
cin >> temp;
if (temp == "YES") {
    tRads += (age * 0.01);
}
else {}
```

Note this will skip if the user inputs "yes", "y", "Yes" or anything other than exactly "YES". How you deal with this is up to you, but `std::tolower` and `std::transform` may help somewhat.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed and very helpful comment, and your second suggestion seemed to fix it. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think with sleep() comes undefined behavior, you should test it without, the os handles user-input and you do not have to care about the user typing in. `endl` flushes cout, so the text is directly shown.

Edit:

Maybe system("CLS") or sleep produces a silent error.

Comment: oops, i forgot to add that i declared it

Comment: Why would it have undefined behaviour? That thing's been around since the dawn of time.

Comment: @tadman the posix sleep(int) function  has indeed been around for a long time, but that doesn't seem to be the sleep function the OP is calling.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ah, that much is true. I'm still not sure that's the culprit here.

Comment: i created a void function for it, but didnt include it in the post. sorry for the misunderstanding and I hope you can still help me.

Comment: @firetto It's always important to build code up from a *minimal*, functional base, and add things incrementally, testing that they're *still* working. You have a lot of code here that could be put aside to verify that one aspect of your code is working.